# (Biztalk) Why am I seeing message type does not exist or is invalid for a referenced schema?

Tags: namespaces, xsd, biztalk, message-type

I've got a Biztalk solution that I'm trying to break apart into the recommended deployment artifacts (Schemas, Maps, and Orchestrations each in a separate DLL), and I'm having a little trouble with one schema in particular.

The orchestration in which I'm using the schema has a single message defined using the schema type.  In orchestration view, this message has the error icon (!) beside it.  When I hover over the icon, I see "Message Type 'BiztalkPilot.MyMessageType' does not exist or is invalid."

If I change the type's compilation instruction so that it resides in, say, the BiztalkPilotSchema namespace, then the whole thing works.  Every other schema in the project is in the BiztalkPilot namespace and they all function correctly.

Obviously I could just switch namespaces and have done with it, but I would like to not have to go there if possible.  Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the .dll's from the gac and building?

Comment: None of the DLLs are in the GAC on the build machine.  I'm using project references for resolution.

Comment: Try flipping the copy local from true to false, back to true, for the schema assembly, in the references for the orchestration.

Comment: Sadly that did not work either.  I've actually been having to remove and re-reference the schemas assembly  from the orchestration project references every time I rebuild it, so I don't think a stale or corrupted reference could be to blame here.

Comment: And no trace of any of these assemblies in the gac?  It's never deployed locally?

Comment: When you moved the schema to the new project, did you change the type.  Under properties when you have the schema file selected in solution explorer.

Comment: I don't have a Biztalk server on the local box, just the dev tools.  My development server is on a separate box and several developers share access.  The issue I'm having is purely in the development toolset.

Comment: I didn't change the schema type, no.  It was originally in the BizTalkPilot dll, which is why it has the namespace it does.  Almost all other Biztalk artifacts in the solution share that same namespace for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the root cause here.  The orchestration shared the same name as the schema.  I'm not sure why that worked when they were in a common project, but once I changed the typename of the orchestration everything worked correctly.

Comment: Glad you found it, here is another interesting way to organize artifacts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136315/biztalk-project-naming-conventions

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  We're actually moving away from this deployment strategy; it's very difficult to patch this scheme when you version-stamp your Biztalk DLLs due to the admin console's inability to distinguish between different schema versions or update the schema version stamp on the fly.